# SideMenu - Wrong width on smartphones and Simulator with smartphone skin

Tags: codenameone

In our app, the `SideMenu` is build with several calls to `getToolbar().addComponent(Component, Command)`.

On tablets and tablet skinned simulator, no problem.

On smartphones and smartphone skinned simulator, the menu is shrinked to +- 10% of the width of the screen when in portrait orientation, which is of course way too thin to show the content of the menu. But when in landscape orientation no problem, and sidemenu width is greater than 10%.

I've tried with and without `Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu`, same behavior.

Here is the snipped used to add an item to the menu (called from a `Form`):

```
getToolbar().addComponentToLeftSideMenu(
    createMenuItem(tr.translate("app.menu.home")), //tr.translate retrieve the translated key
    Command.create("", 
            null, 
            ev-> initAndShowForm()));
```

Here is the createMenuItem method :

```
public static Container createMenuItem(String title, Image leftIcon)
{
    Container menuItem = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
    menuItem.setUIID("MenuItemContainer");

    Label label = new Label(title);
    label.setUIID("MenuItemLabel");
    menuItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);
    Label leftIconLabel = null;
    if(leftIcon != null)
    {
        leftIconLabel = new Label(leftIcon);
        leftIconLabel.setUIID("MenuItemLabel");
        menuItem.add(BorderLayout.WEST, leftIconLabel);
    }
    Label rightIconLabel = new Label(Fly.theme.getImage("icon-arrow.png"));
    rightIconLabel.setUIID("MenuItemLabel");
    menuItem.add(BorderLayout.EAST, rightIconLabel);
    if(leftIconLabel != null)
        Component.setSameHeight(label, leftIconLabel, rightIconLabel);
    else
        Component.setSameHeight(label, rightIconLabel);

    return menuItem;
}
```

Here are two screenshots from the simulator (it's exactly the same behavior on real device). Nexus 5 skin on the left, iPad 3 on the right:
[image]

Here are the UIID constraints for the components :

MenuItemContainer:

- Background none
- Background color + transparency
- Alignment left
- Margin LR 30px, TB 20px

MenuItemLabel:

- Foreground color + transparency
- Alignment left

SideNavigationPanel:

- Background image_scaled to get the gradient

I don't understand what can cause such behavior, my parameters don't seem exotic to me...

Comment: Did you define the theme constants that set the side menu width? 
Try commenting out your code and just doing one call `getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToLeftSideMenu("", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO, e -> {});` if this will work it means the problem is in the code that adds the commands. If it would still show a problem it would mean the problem is somewhere in the styling

Comment: I've checked the constants tab of my theme file, and you were right, some old constants were causing this behavior. Thanks for the advise